# Adjoint functors and the classical adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, adjoint-functors

Is there any relationship between adjoint functors seen in category theory, and the classical adjoint (as in adjoint matrices)?

Comment: There is at the very least a superficial similarity.  Given an operator $T$ of a hilbert space, you have $\langle Tx,y \rangle = \langle x,T^*y \rangle$, while for adjoint functors you have $\operatorname{Hom}_C(Fx,y)=\operatorname{Hom}_C(x,Gy)$.  There is probably a way of viewing Hilbert spaces in a nonstandard way to turn the classical adjoint functor as an adjoint functor, but I have not come across one.  I think the superficial similarity is what inspired the name, and for me, it is enough to serve as a mnemonic..

Comment: @Aaron The classical adjoint is actually the adjugate (the transpose of the cofactor matrix), not the Hermitian conjugate.

Answer (score 1):

[Adjoint functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functors) and [adjoint matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose)* (and more generally, viewing matrices as linear operators between finite Hilbert spaces, [Hermitian adjoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint)) are both special cases of the notion of [adjoint morphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjunction) in a [bicategory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bicategory).

Adjoint functors between small categories are precisely adjunctions in the 2-category [$\mathbf{Cat}$](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cat) of small categories.

On the other hand, we may view any monoidal category $\mathcal V$ as a bicategory $\Sigma \mathcal V$, called the [delooping of $\mathcal V$](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/delooping), with a single object $\star$, for which $\Sigma\mathcal V(\star, \star) := \mathcal V$. An adjoint in $\Sigma\mathcal V$ is a [dualisable object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dualizable+object). Every 2-cell between left adjoints $L \to L'$ in a bicategory induces a 2-cell between their right adjoints $R' \to R$, called its [conjugate](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/mate). Consequently, every morphism between dualisable objects induces a morphism in the opposite direction between their duals, called the [dual morphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dual+morphism). Now, for every field $k$, there is a [category of vector spaces over $k$](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Vect), denoted $\mathbf{Vect}_k$. This category is monoidal with respect to the [tensor product of vector spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tensor+product+of+vector+spaces), and the dualisable objects are precisely the finite vector spaces. For every linear operator $A$ between finite vector spaces, the dual morphism associated to a linear operator $A$ is precisely its adjoint/transpose $A^*$.

This explains the similarity between the two constructions, and justifies the shared terminology.

(*As opposed to [adjugate matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix)/classical adjoints, which I believe are unrelated to adjoints in category theory.)